# Как узнать какая версия nuget установлена?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Как узнать какая версия nuget установлена?
Если просто ввести:

```
PM> Get-Package -ListAvailable
```

то это может быть версией?

```
NuGet.Core   {2.14.0}    NuGet.Core is the core framework assembly for NuGet that the rest of NuGet builds upon.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что у вас в вопросе, это версия библиотеки, которая используется Nuget менеджером.

Версия же самого менеджера отображается в консоли:

> Package Manager Console Host Version 3.4.4.1321

А также в Tools -> Extensions and Updates:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]